# Grover's algorithm for 3SAT problem gives erroneous results

Tags: qiskit, grovers-algorithm, ibm-quantum-devices

I'm writing some code in python with Qiskit that implements Grover's algorithm to solve the 3-SAT problem, but when I run it it doesn't give the correct annswer. I've checked the circuit with the `QuantumCircuit.draw()` function and I can't find any error. The result should be one of the possible answers that satisfy the function.

Here's the code and the circuit together with the result it outputs:

[image: Output]

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer, IBMQ
import math
import random 
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
import qiskit

variables = 3
clausules = 2
treball = variables - 2
temp = clausules - 1
total = variables + clausules + treball + temp


funcio = [['0', '-1', '-2'], ['0', '1', '2']]

pro_vars = []
pro_vals = []

# Process input
for i in range(len(funcio)):
    pro_vars.append([])
    pro_vals.append([])
    
    for j in range(len(funcio[i])):
        
        if funcio[i][j][0] == '-':
            pro_vals[i].append(0)
            pro_vars[i].append(int(funcio[i][j][1]))
        
        else:
            pro_vals[i].append(1)
            pro_vars[i].append(int(funcio[i][j]))

#Quantum algorithm
opt_iter = 1#int(math.pi / 4 * math.sqrt(2**variables))

simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')

circuit = QuantumCircuit(variables + clausules + treball + temp + 1, variables)

# Qubit inicialization
for i in range(variables):
    circuit.h(i)

circuit.h(total)
circuit.x(total)

def grover():
    
    #Set work qubits to state 0
    for i in range(variables, variables + treball):
        circuit.reset(i)
    
    
    #Oracle
    for i in range(clausules):
        for j in range(3):
            
            if (pro_vals[i][j] == 0):
                circuit.x(int(pro_vars[i][j]))
        
        control = circuit.qbit_argument_conversion(range(variables))
        
        work = circuit.qbit_argument_conversion(range(variables, variables + treball))
        
        target = circuit.qbit_argument_conversion(variables + treball + i)
        
        circuit.barrier()
        circuit.OR(control, target[0], work)
        circuit.barrier()
        
        for k in range(treball):
                
                circuit.reset(variables + k)    
            
                
        for j in range(len(pro_vars[i])):
        
            if pro_vals[i][j] == 0:
                circuit.x(pro_vars[i][j])    
    
    circuit.ccx(variables + treball, variables + treball + 1, variables + treball + clausules)
    
    for i in range(0, temp - 1):
        control1 = variables + treball + 2 + i
        control2 = variables + treball + clausules + i
        targetf = control2 + 1
        circuit.ccx(control1,control2, targetf)
    
    circuit.cx(total - 1, total)
    circuit.barrier()

    #Grover diffusion operator
    for i in range(variables):
        circuit.h(i)
        circuit.x(i)
        
    circuit.h(variables-1)
    
    circuit.ccx(0,1,variables)
    
    for i in range(0,variables-3):
        circuit.ccx(i+2, variables + i, variables + 1 + i)
        t1 = variables + 1 + i
    circuit.cx(2 * (variables - 1) - 1, variables - 1)
    circuit.barrier()
    circuit.h(variables-1)    
    circuit.barrier()
    for i in range(variables):
        circuit.x(i)
        circuit.h(i)


for i in range(opt_iter):
    grover()        

circuit.measure(range(variables), range(variables))    

job = execute(circuit, simulator, shots=1024)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(circuit)

print("function: ", funcio)

plot_histogram(counts)

#circuit.draw()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello :) could you give an example of the output you are getting?